# Send push Notification in Ionic

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification

I am working on an ionic application and need to implement push notifications using the back end API's developed in .NET.

While going through few blogs I found fire base API's and was able to complete a POC using Firebase. However the notification did not show when the app was in foreground.

I am not sure how to consume .NET API's to get the push messages. Can we achieve this without using Firebase. Please suggest. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal so that notification not show on forground using firebase notifications.

```
this.firebase.onNotificationOpen().subscribe( (msg) => { 
    if (this.platform.is('ios')) { 
        this.presentToast(msg.aps.alert);
         //here notfication in ios
    } else { 
        this.presentToast(msg.body); 
        //here notfication in android
    } 
});
```

This will trigger a toast of notification in foreground. If you want it as notfication, use local notfication and set the msg.body details as it should be shown inside the local notfication.

And as an advice, use onesignal notfication since it contains better features plus easier and more flexible.

Comment: Thanks @Mostafa ! Can we integrate FCM and OneSignal services in .NET for push and record messages ?

Comment: Do you mean by record notification like schedule notfications?

Comment: Yes, I wish to send notification to specific people individually based on some conditions in my database. I have developed my API's using .NET.

Comment: Yes you can easily using onesignal api, all you need is to add includedSegments: [and send user player id's] and add sendAfter:time to sent at for schedule